# what is the libinput calibration matrix?

Tags: 22.04, touchscreen, libinput

I am trying to find the libinput calibration matrix and what data goes into the values. This is for a Panasonic CF-31 toughbook. I need to have the touchscreen device handled by libinput instead of evdev